# MouseMove Function and Modules

Tags: module, vb6, mousemove

i have a program to create for school and the mouse move function are taking up a lot of space and making it a messy project. My question, Is there a way to move the functions to a module?

These are just some of the MouseMove functions:

```
Private Sub Frame4_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
   StatusBar1.SimpleText = "Ready..."
End Sub

Private Sub Text2_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
StatusBar1.SimpleText = "First Name of Student"
End Sub

Private Sub Text3_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
StatusBar1.SimpleText = "Last Name of Student"
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: I don't have a problem with this code, but you could try putting the status text into the controls `Tag` property. You could then use a single method that takes a control as a parameter, has an error handler in case the control does not have a `Tag` property to read, reads the `Tag` and writes the text to StatusBar1.SimpleText. That is still going to leave you calling your method from each controls MouseMove event and gains you little. If you're really feeling ambitious you could write your own textbox control and raise your own event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are pre-defined events that belong to the form. You can't move them out of the form into a module.

You create a module with a StatusBarUpdate function that you called everytime you wanted to change the status bar ... but ... that hardley seems worthwhile to replace one line of code with one line of code

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, ill just keep the status bar codes at the bottom so they do not interfere with the other codes.